# Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class config does not exist' in vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class  config does not exist' in  D:\laragon\www\project\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:738

I am trying to use `dompdf` in laravel and according to that documentation.

Lumen:

After updating composer add the following lines to register provider in bootstrap/app.php

```
$app->register(\Barryvdh\DomPDF\ServiceProvider::class);
```

To change the configuration, copy the config file to your config folder and enable it in bootstrap/app.php:

```
$app->configure('dompdf');
```

and i add that code in bootstrap/app.php like this

```
$app->register(\Barryvdh\DomPDF\ServiceProvider::class);
$app->configure('dompdf');
```

but i am geting that error.

Comment: Is this Lumen, Laravel 5, 5.1 or 5.2 - There are some significant differences between them. Could you clean up the tags or specifically say which you are actually using. You mentioned all of them here.

Comment: Have you run "composer update"

Comment: Make sure you don't have .env variables with spaces.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't use Lumen, remove the configuration you've probably done, regarding instructions, in bootsrap/app.php

Answer (score 1):

I found this error after using the DomPDF package in laravel. this error comes up whenever I use DomPDF.so that I found one solution for that as below which is worked for me.

comment this line in app_name -> bootstrap -> app.php

```
$app->register(\Barryvdh\DomPDF\ServiceProvider::class);
```

comment these 2 lines in app_name -> config -> app.php

```
  'PDF' => Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade::class,
  Barryvdh\DomPDF\ServiceProvider::class,
```

after that into your project run command `composer update`

execute below commands when the update is done successful,

```
php artisan clear-compiled 
composer dump-autoload
php artisan optimize
```

after that reinstall, DomPDF into your project `composer require barryvdh/laravel-dompdf`   uncomment all above 3 lines and run `php artisan serve`

your project will start running again.

Comment: Works like magic!

Answer (score -1):

```
$app->register(\Barryvdh\DomPDF\ServiceProvider::class);
```

Added to a `error dir,`

You should register it in /`root/config/app.php,`